# Hiding the piwik top menu

Tags: php, matomo

I am using `piwik` `analytics` but i want to hide the top bar of the `piwik` when i view that in an iframe

http://prntscr.com/i5n3dy

how can do it, i tried looking into the code but it is using framework which i am not aware of and anything which i can write in the config file so it should not display in the `iframe` itself.

I went through the code documentation but could not find such information and even checked the github but to no avail, i found somewhere we can use use keycombination to z to hide it, but that is temporary solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

If you only wan't to show the dashboard, widgets would solve your issue.

When you use the following URL ([try it out](https://demo.matomo.org/index.php?module=Widgetize&action=iframe&moduleToWidgetize=Dashboard&actionToWidgetize=index&idSite=3&period=week&date=yesterday)), it will only show the dashboard without the top navbar and the sidebar.

`https://demo.matomo.org/index.php?module=Widgetize&action=iframe&moduleToWidgetize=Dashboard&actionToWidgetize=index&idSite=3&period=week&date=yesterday`

Otherwise you may wan't to look into [theming](https://developer.matomo.org/guides/theming) to apply custom CSS.